# To draw the graph like Structure along with the Radiobutton?

Tags: android, graph

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GOUa.jpg)

As I am beginner in android so I don't know the name of this structure exactly but i have highlighted it in rectangle shape...

I have to design this in xml is it possible to design it in xml??

If not how it can be done???
I have a screen like this a graph like structure along with 4 Radiobuttons.The data in the radio button wont be static it might change. I just want the radio buttons over the line of the graph and it might not vary if the screen size changes.

So all in all i want to implement this graph like structure with radio button does any one has any idea what this is called originally and how it will be implemented 
Thanks in advance :-)

Comment: Check this https://github.com/lecho/hellocharts-android

Comment: ok Sir but can you elaborate in detail that how how i will place the radio buttons on the graph???